# How to make a cell value as chart title using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make cell A1 as chart title. I used the given below code. But it didn't worked.

```
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "HSI of" & Cells(1, 1).Value
```

I want the chart title as "HSI of" "*******cell value(in my case A1)**********"

Comment: Check value in your A1 cell. It's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the `HasTitle` property of the chart to `True` before assigning the title.

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "HSI of " + Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Comment: I tried . Its not coming. "HSI of" is coming , but A1 value is not displaying .

Comment: Are you using `+` to combine? Its working for me. I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: I think it is because of I am selecting the chart area excluding A1.

Comment: No. That is not the issue. I tried to give title as a cell value in chart area. Still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your second line of code looks good. Let's see if you can tweak the first line to get the desired results. Try this, assuming your chart is the first one in the active sheet:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "HSI of " & Cells(1,1).Value
```

This code activates the first chart object in your current sheet and then changes the title.

Comment: "HSI of" is coming , but A1 value is not displaying . But There is value in A1 cell.

Comment: I think it is because of I am selecting the chart area excluding A1.

Comment: No. That is not the issue. I tried to give title as a cell value in chart area. Still not working

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your excel sheet that shows your chart and cell A1? Also please upload a screenshot of the VBA code you are running.

Comment: Can you please give me your mail id? I am working in a project and there are some restrictions to post it here.

Comment: You can try s30771726 at streetwisemail dot com