# Automating production of graphs using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts

I have a large number of graphs to produce and am trying to avoid creating and formatting them manually.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWelj.png)
I have linked an image of the data above, with the row labels omitted for data security. I need a line graph for each time series row of data, where the title of each graph is the row label in leftmost column and x axis labels are the column labels. I am able to create graphs in a for loop but am running into issues when assigning chart titles and x axis labels. I've read other posts and the fixes haven't helped. The code so far is as follows:

```
Sub main()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim chrtname As String

    'Find the last used row
    'LastRow = Sheets("Chart Data").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = 272
    'Find the last used column
    'LastColumn = Sheets("Chart Data").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    LastColumn = 15
    'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
    For i = 86 To LastRow
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        'Adds chart to the sheet
        Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        'sets the chart type
        chrt.ChartType = xlLine

        'adding line chart
        With Sheets("Charts Data")
            chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
        End With

        'adjust the position of chart on sheet
        chrt.ChartArea.Left = 1
        chrt.ChartArea.Top = (i - (i *0.5)) * chrt.ChartArea.Height
        
        'Trying to set a chart title
        chrt.HasTitle = True
        chrtname = Cells(i, 2).Value
        chrt.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        chrt.ChartTitle.Select
        chrt.ChartTitle.Text = chrtname
        
        'Trying to add x axis labels
        chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Charts Data!$C$3:$O$3"
    
    
        Next

End Sub
```

If I type text for the chart title in "" it works, but otherwise the chart title seems to get deleted when trying to assign a cell value, a similar problem another user seemed to have. [How to make a cell value as chart title using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771726/how-to-make-a-cell-value-as-chart-title-using-vba)

This was resolved privately so any guidance appreciated. I also need to add in an extra data series which is the same across all charts but am yet to succeed at that either.

I apologise as this is likely a very basic question but I am new to VBA.

Comment: I would look to using a template sheet with the chart set to pick up the labels from specific cells.

Answer (score 1):

for the title issue, you have to change:

```
chrtname = Cells(i, 2).Value
```

to:

```
chrtname = Sheets("Charts Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

since without explicit reference to sheet parent object, a range object would implicitly assume the currently active sheet, which you made to be "Sheet2" by mans of the `Sheets("Sheet2").Select` statement

while as to the XValues issue, you have to change:

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Charts Data!$C$3:$O$3"
```

to:

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Charts Data'!$C$3:$Q$3"
```

since a sheet name with spaces must be enclosed by single quotation marks

But you might want to consider this sort of a refactoring of your code which extensively uses the `With .. End With` construct to have better grasp on which object is currently under you "hold"

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart

    'Find the last used row
    'LastRow = Sheets("Chart Data").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = 272
    'Find the last used column
    'LastColumn = Sheets("Chart Data").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    LastColumn = 15
    'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
    
    With Sheets("Charts Data") ' reference data sheet
        For i = 86 To LastRow
    
            'Adds chart to the Sheet2
            Set chrt = Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            
            'adding line chart
            chrt.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, LastColumn))
            
            With chrt ' reference the just added chart

                'sets the chart type
                .ChartType = xlLine
        
                'adjust the position of chart on sheet
                .ChartArea.Left = 1
                .ChartArea.Top = (i - (i * 0.5)) * chrt.ChartArea.Height
                
                'Trying to set a chart title
                .HasTitle = True
                
                'add x axis labels
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Charts Data'!$C$3:$Q$3"

            End With
            
            chrt.ChartTitle.Text = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```